# Getting records between current date and next x days in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

Hope someone can help me out. I'm trying convert a line of SQL to work with Presto. Currently in SQL I do the following to get all records that are due in the next 0-5 days:

`((EventStartDate)between getdate()-1 and dateadd(day, 5, getdate()))`

I thought it would be something like this in Presto

`EventStartDate between current_date and interval '5' day`

But get the following error in AWS Athena: *Cannot check if date is BETWEEN date and interval day to second*

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interval needs a date or timestamp to be used and BETWEEN can only be made between to equal entities to dates twp timestamps two numbers

So do this instead

```
 EventStartDate between current_date and current_date + interval '5' day
```